# Prevent NaN values for anomaly detection for Isolation Forests

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm currently working with a dataset and every time I use an isolation forest for anomaly detection, the vast majority of the data is classified as NaN instead of 1 (inlier) or -1 (outlier). Here's a version of the code I currently use.

```
def IsolatedForestAnomalyDetection(df):
    df1 = df.drop(['a','b','c', 'd'], axis = 1)
    data = df1
    X = np.array(df1)
    clf = IsolationForest(contamination = 0.01, n_estimators=10)
    clf.fit(X)  # fit 10 trees  
    df1["iforest"] = pd.Series(clf.predict(data))
    return(df1)
```

Basically, I send in a pandas data frame and drop unnecessary columns then proceed with the isolation forest and add the results from the anomaly detection to a data frame and return it. Is there something wrong with the way I set up Isolation Forest or does it most likely have something to do with the data frame I sent or both?

Comment: Could you provide a minimal csv that reproduces the issue?

Answer (score 1):

It happened to me too.
The problem came from the index of my dataframe.
Try to reset the index first.